# ggplot Error: Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type function

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, stacked

I plotted a stacked bar graph in R using ggplot2 package,

```
 data<-read.table("K.txt",header=TRUE, sep="\t")
> data
  Sample   P1   P2   P3   P4
1     G1 0.02 0.01 0.03 0.95
2     G2 0.01 0.01 0.02 0.97
3     G3 0.01 0.01 0.02 0.97
4     G4 0.01 0.01 0.02 0.97
5     G5 0.01 0.01 0.02 0.96
6     G6 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.98
7     G7 0.05 0.01 0.01 0.93
8     G8 0.34 0.01 0.01 0.64
9     G9 0.43 0.01 0.01 0.56
> library("reshape2", lib.loc="C:/Program Files/R/R-2.15.2/library")
> data1<-melt(data)
Using Sample as id variables
> head(data1)
   Sample variable value
1      G1       P1  0.02
2      G2       P1  0.01
3      G3       P1  0.01
4      G4       P1  0.01
5      G5       P1  0.01
> library("ggplot2", lib.loc="C:/Program Files/R/R-2.15.2/library")
ggplot(data=data1, aes(x=sample, y=value, fill=variable))+geom_bar(width=1)+scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))+ opts(axis.text.x=theme_text(angle=90))
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type function. Defaulting to continuous
Error in data.frame(x = function (x, size, replace = FALSE, prob = NULL)  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 36
```

Can any1 help me to sort out this error?

Many thanks
Ramesh

Comment: `x=Sample` you are using `sample` which is inbuit function

Comment: Noise? I found this really helpful: music to my ears.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Change `sample` (built-in function) to `Sample` (your variable)

```
ggplot(data=data1, aes(x=Sample, y=value, fill=variable)) +
    geom_bar(width=1) +
    scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
    opts(axis.text.x=theme_text(angle=90))
```