# Stacked Bar Chart Error in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a stacked bar chart using r. I know a bit of R, but mainly SPSS. The barcharts are really ugly in SPSS so I have been trying to use ggplot2 to make something more elegant.

Following other posts, I have tried to make my variables work. I converted the data to long form. Because this is original research I can't give too many specifics on the case. The first column is categorical data, and the second is numeric, because I imported it from SPSS but is actually categorical as well.

In longform there are 110 obs and 2 variables. My code here is:

`Barchart <- ggplot(psydatacomp, aes(x=PsyType, y=Agreement, fill=row)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")`

psydatacomp is the matrix I created in order to remove the NaN's.

The error message I receive is:

`Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type function. Defaulting to continuous.
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 110, 0`

I have a basic backing in R, but it's not strong enough to be able to interpret what this error message is saying. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that one of your variables is interpreted as a function. For example "row" is a function (just search ?row in R). You should change here the column name from "row" to "Row". 
Here is a similar case: [ggplot Error: Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22058322/ggplot-error-dont-know-how-to-automatically-pick-scale-for-object-of-type-func)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to R would be to run the analysis in SPSS and use Excel to visualize your results. It's much easier to run a simple SPSS analysis and drop the output into Excel than to import to R. A stacked bar chart takes no time to produce in Excel. I only mention this because it sounds like you are new to R but are more familiar with SPSS.

Comment: So after lots of work I was able to do this in R, but would have probably saved a lot of my time, having done the initial data manipulation in r rather than importing into spss.